# Is imprecision of a double value guaranteed to be consistent on the same machine?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy

We know that `double`s loose precision of their value as you increase the number of decimal points. But if I use the same `double` value twice on the same machine will I be *guaranteed* to have the same imprecision? For example:

```
double d1 = 123.456;//actually becomes 123.45600001
double d2 = 123.456;//is guaranteed to become 123.45600001?
```

For simplicity sake lets stick with just C++.

Comment: Most C++ implementations conform to the IEEE floating point standard. So, yes.

Comment: @callyalater, no, it does not.

Comment: @SergeyA You're right. I meant to say [most implementations are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#C_and_C.2B.2B).

Comment: Note that the answer for comparing two values initialized from identical literals is _very_ different than the answer for comparing two values initialized from any other sources. `.2` is almost never equal to `.1+.1`

Comment: When exact equality matters, I have sometimes tried to avoid that very problem by creating the value only once, and referring to it in various places, even if I have to make it a global. Of course, the decision to do that would depend on various nuances of the program as a whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not have this guarantee. C++ implementations are not bound by IEEE standard, and can choose any binary represenation they want.

While they are unlikely to just invent their own, they usually have fluctuate (even within the same vendor) in how thew represent the 'nonrepresentable' numbers - they can be represented with a bigger number or a smaller number - and this representation changes (I believe, even different floating math options for **same** gcc can affect this).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `d1` has to equal `d2` in the OP's example.  I don't think you could have an implementation that converts the same literal into two different values.  It is true though that `123.456` does not have to equal `123 + .456`

Comment: @NathanOliver, I didn't took the question literally and thought those equasions there are just for illustration. However, it is not hard to imagine implementation which would hav those two variables not comparing equally - imagine it uses an FPU chip which rounds up or down depending on random value - to reduce bias/

Comment: Random rounding is not one of the allowed IEEE 754 rounding modes. These are:

1. round to nearest, ties to even,
2. round to nearest, ties away from zero,
3. round toward zero,
4. round toward +∞,
5. round toward -∞

In all of these modes, rounding is applied when two values are equally distant from the given value. In no case should a compiler choose a representation that is farther from the given decimal constant than another legal value.

Comment: @SteveHollasch, but C++ implementation is not required to follow IEEE standard.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, `d1 == d2` will return `true`, and it will *almost* always return true on any properly operating compiler/architecture. Even if the compiler/architecture aren't IEEE conforming, it's extremely unlikely that providing an identical symbol for `123.456` would return different values on multiple invocations.

But, if you had the following code:

```
double d1 = 123.456;
double d2 = get_123_456_from_network_service(service);
```

That guarantee would cease to be. `123.456` will be exactly the same on your computer all the time, but if a different computer attempts to use the same symbol, and isn't IEEE conforming (or if yours isn't), then there's a good chance the values would be different.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler conforms to the IEEE 754 (IEC 559) standard, they should be the same. You can check if it is IEEE compliant with [`std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/is_iec559). Most implementations are IEEE compliant, but this is not a guarantee.